# How to put sql query in an array in yii

Tags: mysql, yii

I have a line like this:

```
 $line= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('line_no')->from('tblvehicleimage') ->where('serial_no=:serial_no', array(':serial_no'=>$model->serial_no)) ->queryScalar();
```

how to put all the $line data in an array? Is there any way i can use 'mysql_fetch_array'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryScalar` means only one record will be retrieved.

You want to use `serial_no IN (1, 2, 3)` for example, and `queryAll()` instead of `queryScalar()`.

```
$serial_nos = array(1, 2, 3);
$serial_nos = implode($serial_nos);

$line = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('line_no')
        ->from('tblvehicleimage')
        ->where('serial_no IN ('.$serial_nos.')')
        ->queryAll();
```

Once the query is successful, `$line` will contain an array, you then simply have to loop through the results:

```
foreach ($line as $key=>$item) {
    // do something with each $item
}
```

Comment: o ok, so queryScalar  was the problem..; thnx a lot.

Comment: using findAll() giving error: CDbCommand and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "findAll".

Maybe it wil be queryAll()?

Comment: it will give you an error obviously because querybuilder method does not support find().

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to select only **line_no** from the table, you can also use `queryColumn()`

```
$line = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('line_no')
        ->from('tblvehicleimage')
        ->where('serial_no IN ('.$serial_nos.')')
        ->queryColumn();
```

If you want one-dimensional array like

```
array(1,2,3)
```

as your result then you can use **queryColumn()**
But if you want

```
array(array(1),array(2),array(3))
```

as your answer then you can use **queryAll()**.
Choice is yours :)